# Question about derivatives with Leibniz notation in differential geometry

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, differential

Let $c:I\to\mathbb{R}$ a regular curve with curvature $k > 0, \forall t\in I$. 
Then, $k(t)=\frac{||\dot{c}(t)\times\ddot{c}(t)||}{||\dot{c}(t)||^3}$, where $\dot{c}$ and $\ddot{c}$ are first and second derivative of function $c$. 
Ok, so this is the context. Now, my proof starts with:

> Let $s$ = natural parameter of curve. Then $\frac{dc}{dt} = \frac{dc}{dt}\frac{dt}{ds}$.
> Let $h$ be the inverse function of $s$. So, $h(s)=t$. Then, $\frac{dc}{ds}(h(s))=\frac{dc}{dt}(h(s))\frac{dh}{ds}$ [...]

I am not familiar with Leibniz notation for derivatives. Can someone explain me why is the last statement true, and how it works?

Comment: The Leibniz notation is, despite its flaws, convenient for working in elementary differential geometry. That said, the end of the first line you quoted is garbage, and your text's notation is extraordinarily cumbersome. For starters, I suggest you look at pp. 7-8 and then 12-13 of *my* differential geometry text, linked in my profile. Here, I would start with $\gamma(s)=c(h(s))$ and the chain rule gives $\gamma'(s)=c'(h(s))h'(s)$. Your book will write $\frac{dc}{ds}=\frac{dc}{dt}(h(s))\frac{dt}{ds}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I still don't understand. Why $\frac{dt}{ds} = h'(s)$

Comment: It's the second line you copied there. "So, $h(s)=t$." This means $h'(s)=dt/ds$.

Comment: @TedShifrin but from your relation from your first comment, how can I get my relation $\frac{dc}{ds}(h(s))=\frac{dc}{dt}(h(s))\frac{dh}{ds}$ ? Sorry for bother you but I really want to understand.

Comment: Because they’re using $c$ for two different functions. The LHS is $\gamma’(s)$.

Comment: @TedShifrin  Another question. $\frac{dc}{ds}\small{h(s)}$is the evaluation of $\frac{dc}{ds}$ in $h(s)$ or it says that function $c$ is a function in terms of $h(s)$?